# "Init(URL:)" has been renamed to "init(url:)" - swift 3 wkwebview error

Tags: swift, url, wkwebview, xcode8

First time using webkit alongside swift 3, and I keep getting this error regarding a web view load request.  Why is Xcode announcing the renaming but maintaining the error?

```
var webView: WKWebView!
var websites = ["apple.com", "hackingwithswift.com"]

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://" + websites[0])!
    webView.load(NSURLRequest(URL: url as URL) as URLRequest)
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Just drop NS and create URLRequest and URL objects in Xcode 8 Swift 3

Comment: Like this? Webview.load(URLRequest(URL: url as URL).  ?

Comment: No need to cast from NSURL to URL, just create URL(string:). Let Xcode autocomplete it for you. If you woukd like to know only the URL initializers just type URL.init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by *@LeoDabus*, here's the code

```
class Controller: UIViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var websites = ["apple.com", "hackingwithswift.com"]

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://" + websites[0])!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest)
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    }
}
```

Comment: there we go, appreciate it, Appz!

Comment: WKWebView isn't loading JavaScript sign up form in webview ? while in safari this is working fine. any solution @appzYourLife  I used the same code but in vein. simple UIWebView didn't load the same form..any help please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which i solved using following lines of code

```
  let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")

    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    webview.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
```